# Useless question should be deleted?

Tags: support, deletion, self-deletion

I have asked a question and it has turned out to be useless. I misunderstood the statement of a theorem and that is why my doubt was absurd.
The question does not contribute anything and the moderators have not deleted it, but a user has answered it and has obtained a few upvotes for the answer. Should I delete it (and how)?

**Edit**: the question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687156/infinite-trees-with-finite-levels). Finally, I have decided to add to the question an answer in which I prove the result that led me to confusion. I think this, together with the clarification of the statement that I misunderstood, makes the question useful.

Comment: Why not delete it?  If it doesn't add value to the site, why wait for moderators to delete it?

Comment: @XanderHenderson, because a user has answered it and has obtained two upvotes for the answer.

Comment: Then your question really isn't "Should **I** delete the question?" (since you can't, at this point), but "Should the question be deleted?", which is a matter of community moderation, and not something that you have any real control over.  Though you could ask about it in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured).

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the details of closings, deletions, and who can and who should do them is very far from clear. Thanks, Yester, for thinking about this and asking.

Comment: It is pretty common for a misunderstanding to be the root of a Question on Math.SE.  If you had a difficulty of this kind, it is likely to be shared by a future Reader.  With the benefit of hindsight you might search to see if your specific confusion has come up here previously (and if so leave a Comment on your Question linking to the older duplicate).  In any case your meta Question could be improved by linking to your Question on main Math.SE and tagging this here with "specific-question".

Comment: @hardmath, thanks for your comment. I've added some information to the question here.